# Sort records according to value in associated model

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have two models: School and Address.

```
Address
    has_many :schools

School
    belongs_to :address

    t.bigint "address_id"
```

Now I need to build scope in School model to get Schools sorted according to occurence of cities in Address table. So I need following result:

```
School_1 | City_most_popular
School_2 | City_most_popular
School_3 | City_most_popular
School_4 | City_most_popular
School_5 | City_quite_popular
School_6 | City_quite_popular
School_7 | City_not_popular
```

I wrote this:  School.joins(:address).group("schools.id, addresses.city").order("addresses.city ASC") but this only allows to group records by cities and ignore occurence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
School
 .joins(:address)
 .select('schools.*, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY addresses.city) AS count')
 .order('count DESC')
```

Comment: Unfortunately not working on Postgresql. Requires schools.id in grouping clause. I added this but query result is wrong.

Comment: Updated answer. @user2942937